# Is it possible to remove the "Expected '{' and instead saw" error from Ember Cli?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, jshint

I've just started working with Ember cli, and every time I change a file, it spits out JSLint errors found in that file.

This is extremely helpful, except for the fact that it considers the following to be in valid:

```
var isValidJS = true;

if (isValidJS) console.log("This is totally valid JS");
```

It responds with this error: `Expected '{' and instead saw 'console'`

Is there anyway to silence only the errors specific to missing curly braces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool reporting this error is actually [JSHint](http://jshint.com/), not JSLint or Ember. JSHint comes standard in Ember CLI project templates and comes with a certain set of rules. From what I can tell, the [`curly` option](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#curly) is causing your current issue. Open up the `.jshintrc` file in the root of your project and set `curly` to `false` (or delete it entirely).

For what it's worth, I generally remove JSHint completely from my Ember projects. You can either avoid code hinting completely or replace it with the much more configurable [eslint](http://eslint.org/).